# PhpStorm and Laravel autocompletion

Tags: laravel, autocomplete, phpstorm

I decided to use PhpStorm for my new Laravel project, so I thought I wanted some autocompletion. I did read the guide from https://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2015/01/laravel-development-using-phpstorm/ and some of it works fine, but I got a problem.

I wanted to test my DB connection, so I just made a simple `index()` function like this

```
if(DB::connection()->getDatabaseName()) {
    echo 'Connected to ' . DB::connection()->getDatabaseName();
}
```

Which works fine, but when I write `DB` and press <kbd>Tab</kbd> I write `\DB::` instead of `DB::`. Then I include `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;` and `DB::` works. But when I added the facade, the autocompletion isn't the same at all and it cant find the methods but they works. It's really annoying.

Someone else had this problem and is there a solution for it?

Answer (score 13):

In PhpStorm,
Settings => plugins

- Search repository for laravel and install.

Then after add this package:

`composer require barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper`

You can find more help on github for this package:https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper

Answer (score 8):

First, install the Laravel plugin for PhpStorm, then install `laravel-ide-helper`.
After that, generate `ide-helper` for your project)

```
php artisan ide-helper:generate
php artisan ide-helper:meta
```

For correct autocomplete model you must identify this model
**`use (model namespace)`**

Comment: Still adds backslach infront of DB unless i use the facades one. But if i 'use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB' then autocompletion for that one doenst work. Can like DB::connection in the tab (it works in the code)

Comment: For this you must write the use (use DB). After that DB::connection work in tab (i try it in my storm :) )

Comment: Strom must identify the model and than load autocomplete data (methods, variables and consts of this model)

Answer (score 2):

You have to install the helpers - https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper

Comment: Already did. And i did add it as a serviceprovider and then ide-helper:generate, but didnt solve the problem

Comment: does _ide-helper.php appeared in project root? Should be so. You also should have in top of your file.
`use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;`
You may also wish to install phpstorm plugin called laravel - it also helps

Answer (score -2):

Figured it out :) Just att DB to your class and the problem is solved.

```
use DB;
```