# PhpStorm won't open a function in the model

Tags: laravel, phpstorm

I have a function in the `MissingData` model, that is called from the `MissingDataController`:

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
    $missingData = MissingData::where('operation_id', 1)->firstOrFail();
    $missingData->fillData();
}
```

Code works great, but PhpStorm cannot open `fillData()` when using `Ctrl + B`. In general, this happens when `$missingData` is not a `MissingData` model. But here, when I `dd($missingData)`, it returns a `App\Models\MissingData` instance.

I also tried to invalidate PhpStorm Cache, but it didn't work.

Why is it happening ? For all other methods, PhpStorm works fine.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42160204/phpstorm-and-laravel-autocompletion

Comment: I already use laravel-ide-helper ! I will update my question with that

Comment: Did you regenerate it after adding your new method?

Comment: yep, I just did it again, and it didn t work

Answer (score 1):

I would assume that PHPStorm doesn't know that result of  `firstOrFail()` is of type `App\Models\MissingData`. To solve that I would simply add phpdoc:

```php
/** @var \App\Models\MissingData $missingData */
$missingData = MissingData::where('operation_id', 1)->firstOrFail();
```